# exim: remote host is local host?

Tags: email, exim

I don't know much about email servers and I am having some problems.

I am trying to setup exim to forward emails to another port on the local host for testing purposes. Exim should basically connect to my test smtp server and send an email.

Python Test SMTP server: listens on port 9100, when an email is successfully sent, it prints it to the console. I have tested this by telnetting in and manually sending emails and it works fine

I want exim to relay all sent emails to this test server, which is on a different port on the same machine (localhost:9100).

The problem is, I keep getting the following error messages in my main log:

2010-06-24 22:29:17 1ORs6v-0002MP-Vv <= bill@bill-laptop U=bill P=local S=344
2010-06-24 22:29:18 1ORs6v-0002MP-Vv remote host address is the local host: somehwere.com
2010-06-24 22:29:18 1ORs6v-0002MP-Vv == bill@somehwer.com R=smarthost defer (-1): remote host address is the local host

Is there anyway for me to disable this check?

Answer (score 6):

Exim doesn't, by default, let you send mail back to yourself.  You can change this behavior by using the [self router option](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch15.html#id394593).  Here's an example from my config in which I had to use `self = send` to get Exim to send "slow" mail to another instance on the same host:

```
stalemail:
  driver = manualroute
  condition = ${if > {$message_age}{900}{yes}{no}}
  self = send
  domains = ! +local_domains
  route_list = * mailhub-01.example.com::8025:mailhub-02.example.com::8025
  transport = remote_smtp
```

Comment: This filter (stalemail) seems to be about, well, stale mail. :) I was having this problem at a filter called dnslookup; I put it there, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you bind the test server to a different address in the loopback range, such as 127.255.0.1?

Comment: It worked for me when I told it to pass mail onto a 127.1.1.1 smarthost.